# How do I display my subview (PHP) though JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a main PHP file that has content for my main page, say index.php.

Within that page, I call a JavaScript file which runs a function for my button div with a my_subview ID.

Within that function, I have something called content based on a class someone made for me, and when I put 'This is content' in there, it displays that sentence in a modal.

How can I instead have the content display the contents of another PHP file, called subview_php?

Comment: We need to see the code and what you have tried so far (and why it is failing) to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your content div will be:

```
 <div id="content"></div>
 <input type="button" id="my_subview">
 <input type="button" id="subview">
 <div id="wait"></div>
```

Your must use jQuery+Ajax, the code is:

```
 $("#my_subview").click(function(){

     $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"my_subview.php",
        beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#wait').html('<img src="img/Loading.gif"/> Loading Data');                           
                    },
        success:function(data){
              $("#content").html(data); //Show in the div "content" a my_subview.php data
              $('#wait').html('');
        }
        });
 });

 $("#subview").click(function(){

     $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"subview.php",
        beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#wait').html('<img src="img/Loading.gif"/> Loading Data');                           
                    },
        success:function(data){
              $("#content").html(data); //Show in the div "content" a subview.php data
              $('#wait').html('');
        }
     });
});
```

So when you click the first button in the div "content" you will show a my_subview.php dataand when you click in the second button you will show in the same div "content" a subview.php data